# Calculating minimum number alive (MNA)

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm wondering if anyone could help me calculate Minimum Number Alive (MNA) for recapture data.

MNA is calculated by:

> actual number of individuals caught at time (t) + those present, not
>   caught at time (t), but caught subsequently  (Krebs, 1966)

I have binary data (1 for capture, 0 for non-capture) of 9 primary capture periods made up of 44 secondary capture periods for 101 individuals.  I need to condense my secondary period capture data into either a 0 or a 1 for each primary capture period.  This way, I can calculate MNA for each primary capture period.

Much obliged,

Tanya

Comment: You should post output from `dput(head(dat, 30))` where 'dat' is your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to condense your secondary period data.  However, keep in mind that Animals 6 and 10 are known to be alive in the second primary period even though they were not detected then.  Also, Animal 5 is not known to be alive in the first primary period simply because it was detected after the first primary period... ...unless you are assuming no births among primary periods.

In this example there are three primary periods and three secondary periods.

I have not attempted to estimate Minimum Number Alive because I am unclear about your assumptions regarding geographic and demographic closure.  However, hopefully the data summary below is helpful.

```
my.data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*9,1,0.2), nrow = 10, byrow=FALSE))
my.data

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
#2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#4   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#5   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1
#6   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
#7   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#8   1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
#9   0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1
#10  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1

year.sums <- sapply(1:3, function(i)  apply(my.data[,(3*(i-1)+1):(3*(i-0))], 1, function(x) sum(x)) )
year.sums

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    2
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    1    2
# [6,]    1    0    1
# [7,]    3    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    0
# [9,]    0    1    3
#[10,]    1    0    1

year.sums[year.sums>0] <- 1
year.sums

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    1    1
# [6,]    1    0    1
# [7,]    1    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    0
# [9,]    0    1    1
#[10,]    1    0    1
```

Comment: Another method: `t(apply(my.data,1,tapply,rep(1:3,each=3),sum)>0)+0`